# JavaFX add border to ToggleButton graphic

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying to add a border around images in JavaFX `ToggleButtons` and can't find a good way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `ImageView` to a `StackPane` and use the `StackPane` as the graphic node of the `ToggleButton`. Then you can apply a border to the `StackPane`:

```
    ImageView graphic = new ImageView(imageUrl);
    StackPane pane = new StackPane(graphic);
    pane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-width:4; ");

    ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton("", pane);
```